# In the old republic, is the better long term strategy commendations or gear?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

When you complete missions many times you are offered a choice between the current worlds commendation and either some companion gear or personal gear. With crafting and the galactic market, how much are those commendations worth compared to that gear?

Comment: Where can you trade the commendations? I heard about doing that, but was never actually able to do it.

Comment: any commendation vendor.. they are located in the main hub of the orbital station and on the planets themselves. @svick

Comment: I tried the commendation vendors at Imperial Fleet, but they didn't seem to allow me to trade one commendation for another.

Comment: @svick sorry I just assumed about the ones at the imp fleet,you can do it for sure on drommund kas, hutta and balmorre with commendation vendors on each place.  What I have been doing is once I knock off the last non-herioc quest on each planet, I stop by on my way to the ship and trade the commendations up for the next planet.

Comment: @svick and any others that might care, the feature I was talking about was discontinued after beta. Sorry for any wasted time.

Answer (score 2):

The world commendation gear usually lines up with the end of that planet's levels. So if you get much beyond the high end of the planet's difficulty level, then trading up makes sense.

For example, Ord Mantell (1-10) commendations aren't too useful if you're level 25, since few of the Ord Mantell commendation items will be an upgrade for you at that point.

Comment: I am much more interested in if the commendation gear at the end of game is going to make saving them up worthwhile or not... I already have much better gear by the time I am generating the commendations for the planet I am on, but I don't know If it's better to take the quick credits on selling a piece of green gear to the vendors or the lockboxs or gathering the commendations for later.

Comment: @sarge_smith World commendations can be traded for rewards appropriate for the level required by the planet that issued them, as Mufasa said.  So there is no advantage in saving the commendations for later.  Personally I never used commendations for anything but lockboxes until the final couple planets.  There are daily/space/etc. commendations that are useful in the end game, however.

Answer (score 2):

All planetary commendations have been collapsed into Common Data Crystals, and the prices of mods have been greatly reduced.  This means that it is far and away much better to take comms rather than gear.  You should always have enough comms to buy new mods, and modded-out gear at level will always beat the standard green items given as quest rewards.

Comment: It isn't even needed to spend the commendations on leveling gear. Heroics grant much better gear than the quests (although it will never grant a weapon). Most, if not all, heroics can be soloed with some care.

Comment: @Sjoerd True, but levelling is pretty easy even just with standard quest/mob drops -- comm gear should be more than enough and doesn't require as much time as Heroics.

Comment: True. My comment wasn't clear. I fully agree with taking the Common Data Crystals. They are special in the sense that they can be used to buy high level stuff, even when earned on low levels. My intent was to avoid spending the crystals on throwaway gear, saving them for something lasting or expensive instead. Companion gifts, decorations, pets, .... There is a lot that can be bought with Common Data Crystals nowadays.

Comment: @Sjoerd All good points!